# Python alphabet list not correct

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have 2 Python lists with integers (average and avg). Average is sorted revers.
Alphabet is just a list with the alphabet a-z and the last element is the empty string representing the space. Average is the letter frequency of a text file. I'm trying to get a substitution cipher to work for my study.

```
average = [1, 17, 11, 2, 0, 4, 0, 5, 2, 6, 0, 4, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 2, 1, 0, 6, 5, 0, 1, 0, 7, 5]
alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', ' ']

avg = average[:]
average.sort(reverse = True)

for x in range(27):
  for y in range(27):
    if average[x] == avg[y]:
      if y < 26:
        alphabet[x] = chr(97 + y) # ASCII a = 97 
      else:
        alphabet[x] = chr(32) # 32 = space

print(alphabet)
```

For some reason I got this as output:

```
['b', 'c', 'z', 'u', 'u', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'l', 'l', 'q', 'q', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y']
```

Which should normally be a list from a to z (containing whitespace) but
I can't find the error...
Does anyone have a hint?

Comment: Can you show us what `avg` and `average` lists look like?

Comment: What did you actually expect the list to become, and how with that code?

Comment: avg is [1, 17, 11, 2, 0, 4, 0, 5, 2, 6, 0, 4, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 2, 1, 0, 6, 5, 0, 1, 0, 7, 5]
and average ist [17, 11, 7, 6, 6, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] 
and I expect that I get a ['a','b','c',..... 'y','z',' ']
I'm studying media computer science and the loop worked some time and on some point it gave the crazy list.

Comment: Hi @JohnA! Welcome to StackOverflow. I have changed your post to show the values for avg and average and alphabet that you said you had, but the resulting code doesn't show what you say it shows. You can edit and update your own post, and you should do so to show us the values you're actually using.

Comment: @JohnA What's missing from your question is *why*. As evidenced by at least one answer, there are trivial ways to get the alphabet as a list of characters. It's difficult to tell from this question why it's important to go through these hoops to append an empty space to the end of the alphabet.

Comment: Nevermind - you swapped `avg` and `average` in your comment.

Comment: @JohnA I think you are getting the "right" output. It will never give you the right a-z given the numbers you have there. I think what you need is the right interpretation of the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get a-z as a result, `avg` needs to be the same as `average` after reversing and sorting, and all their values need to be unique.

For position 0 in the `alphabet` list to be equal to 'a', you need the `x,y` pair (0,0).

That means that `average[x] == avg[y]` must be true for the following `x,y` pairs:

```
(0, 0)
(1, 1)
(2, 2)
(3, 3)
(4, 4)
(5, 5)
(6, 6)
(7, 7)
(8, 8)
(9, 9)
(10, 10)
(11, 11)
(12, 12)
(13, 13)
(14, 14)
(15, 15)
(16, 16)
(17, 17)
(18, 18)
(19, 19)
(20, 20)
(21, 21)
(22, 22)
(23, 23)
(24, 24)
(25, 25)
(26, 26)
```

Given your code, one value of `average` for which you can expect to get a-z is:

```
average = [27, 26, 25, 24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

**In conclusion**

As for what magic originally made that loop produce a-z, I suspect that the line that now reads as follows:

```
if average[x] == avg[y]:
```

May have originally read as this instead:

```
if x == y:
```

In which case you could throw absolutely any input at it, and it will merrily produce the required a-z.

Answer (score 1):

I honestly don’t get why you expect to get the full alphabet back from that code. Let’s see what happens just for a single value of `x`.

So `x` is `0`, meaning we’re going to fill the first spot. `average` is `avg` in reverse sorted order; and `avg` is a seemingly unrelated list of numbers. So this is what happens for `x = 0`:

```
for y in range(27):
    if average[x] == avg[y]:
        if y < 26:
            alphabet[x] = chr(97 + y) # ASCII a = 97 
        else:
            alphabet[x] = chr(32) # 32 = space
```

`average[x]` is the biggest number, `17`. Now there is only a single spot where `17` occurs in `avg`, namely at index `y=1`. So the inner part of the loop only executes once for `x=0` and `y=1`:

```
if y < 26:
    alphabet[x] = chr(97 + y) # ASCII a = 97 
else:
    alphabet[x] = chr(32) # 32 = space
```

Now `y=1` is obviously smaller than `26` so the first case applies, in which case the character for the alphabet at index `x=0` will be `chr(97 + 1)`. This is not the `a` you apparently expected in the output.

For other `x`, these things happen similarly, except that it gets even more complicated when values for `average[x]` come up that are not unique. In that case, the alphabet character is overwritten multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have no idea what you're trying to *accomplish* with this code, but it's easy enough to figure out why you're getting the result you do get.  Just step through the code!  After the sort, you have this:

```
average = [17, 11, 7, 6, 6, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3,
           2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
avg =     [1, 17, 11, 2, 0, 4, 0, 5, 2, 6, 0, 4,
           1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 2, 1, 0, 6, 5, 0, 1, 0, 7, 5]
```

Now your loop starts looking at `average[0]`, which is 17.  The only index such that `avg[y] == 17` is `y=1`.  So your code does:

```
 alphabet[x] = chr(97 + y) # ASCII a = 97
```

which is:

```
 alphabet[0] = chr(97 + 1)
```

which is:

```
 alphabet[0] = chr(98)
```

which is:

```
 alphabet[0] = 'b'
```

You're done with the first iteration of the outer loop then, so `alphabet[0] == 'b'` is the final value assigned to `alphabet[0]`.

Etc etc etc.  There's nothing surprising here I can see - the code is doing what you told it to do.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to easily get a list from a to z, Python already gives you one:

```
>>> from string import ascii_lowercase
>>> alphabet = ascii_lowercase + ' '
>>> alphabet
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz '
```